# ColdFusion 9 datasources defaulting to enterprise

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have  a ColdFusion instance being run under enterprise, but for some reason it ignores the local data source. It will only connect if I put the data source at the enterprise level.
I've even tried the following code and it only returns the data sources that are declared at the instance manager, not the instance itself.

```
<cfset factory = createObject("java", "coldfusion.server.ServiceFactory")>
<cfset datasources = factory.getDataSourceService().getDatasources()>
<cfloop collection="#datasources#" item="dsnName">
        #dsnName#<br>
 </cfloop>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the site you're running the code under is associated with the instance you're expecting to get the data sources for? If you go to http://thesiteyouwant/cfide/administrator, is it the instance you expect it to be? My assumption is that your site is actually running under the default `cfusion` instance, and not the child instance you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

These should help you figure out which instance you are on:

```
<cfscript>
loc = {};
loc.machineName = createObject('java','java.net.InetAddress').localhost.getCanonicalHostName();
loc.machineName2 = createObject('java','java.net.InetAddress').localhost.getHostName();
loc.hostAddress = createObject('java','java.net.InetAddress').localhost.getHostAddress();
loc.instanceName = createObject('java','jrunx.kernel.JRun').getServerName();
writeDump( var: loc );
</cfscript>
```

If you are having problems getting the datasources you might need to authenticate first with your cf administrator password like so:

```
createObject('component','CFIDE.adminapi.administrator').login('your-password');
```

There is a datasourceExists(), verifyDatasource() and getDatasource() method on the data source service that you might find handy:

```
<cfscript>
loc = {};
loc.dss = createObject('java','coldfusion.server.ServiceFactory').getDataSourceService();
loc.datasources = loc.dss.getDatasources();
loc.exists = loc.dss.datasourceExists('your-dsn');
loc.verified = loc.dss.verifyDatasource('your-dsn');
loc.datasource = loc.dss.getDatasource('your-dsn');
writeDump( var: loc );
</cfscript>
```